# OCaml gets crazy about types

Tags: ocaml

I declared the following function in the interface

```
type t
val empty : t
val mem : int -> t -> bool
```

Now I try to call

```
open ISet
open OUnit2
open Printf
open List
(* ... *)
let s = mem 8 empty
```

But what I get is

```
This expression has type ISet.t but an expression was expected of type
     int list
```

What the heck is going on??
I even explicitly define the types in the .ml file

```
let mem (x : int) (set : t) =
    let rec loop = function
        | Node (l, k, r, _) ->
            let c = cmp_val k x in
            (contains k x) || loop (if c < 0 then l else r)
        | Empty -> false in
    loop set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you provide more code ? t is an abstract type, so I guess somewhere you have to defined it. I suspect also that mem is not the right mem and points to List.mem.

Comment: I agree completely, but it looks like mem points to ISet.mem. There's nothing with that name that comes with OCaml. This suggests there is  *lot* of context missing in OP's description of the problem.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't know that there exists such a thing as `List.mem`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: ``open`` statements are very useful when you want to override a default behavior. Otherwise, I would suggest you use systematically the dotted notation instead (``Iset.mem``) to avoid such confusion.